# How to prove that the fraction is integer by mathematical induction?

Tags: real-analysis, induction, fractions

How can I prove that the fraction

$$P(n) = \frac{1}{60} (7 * 4^n - 42 * (-1)^n - 10) $$

is integer for all natural numbers by mathematical induction method?

I tried to find the difference between $P(k + 1)$ and $P(k)$, but could not transform it to the original fraction.

Comment: Show that $60$ divides the expression by induction. Did you try already $n=1$? The induction has been done several times here, in several variations, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/771410/prove-n2n4-1-is-divisible-by-60-using-mathematical-induction).

Comment: Write $P(n)=Q(n)/60.$  Show that $Q(n+1)-Q(n)$ is divisible by $60$.

Comment: Hint.  it may be easier to use the difference $P(k+2) - P(k)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$P(1)=\frac{1}{60}\left(28+42-10\right)=1$$
$$P(2)=\frac{1}{60}\left(112-42-10\right)=1$$
$$P(k+2)-P(k)=\frac{4^k\times 105}{60}=7\times4^{k-1}$$

Comment: how is $4^k * 112$ divisible by $60$?

Comment: @sku Sorry! Typo. Corrected. Thanks!

Comment: Make it $7 * 4^{k-2}$